# Why does the Taylor series not hold for ln(2/3)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

This should have been a fairly straightforward question: Show that $ln(\frac{2}{3}) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{-1^{n}}{2^n n}$

The Taylor Series expansion: $ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{-1^{n+1}}{n}x^n$ for $|x| < 1$ holds for $ln(\frac{2}{3})$, as the $x$ value would be $1 + x = \frac{2}{3}$, $x = - \frac{1}{3}$. Nevertheless, if you sub $x$ for $-\frac{1}{3}$, you get $ln(\frac{2}{3}) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{-1^{2n}}{-3^nn}$, which is not the same as the desired result.

Why is this the case?

Comment: $\ln\left(2/3\right) = -\ln\left(3/2\right) = -\ln\left(1 + 1/2\right)$.

Comment: Minus signs with no parenthesis can only favor this kind of confusion. Anyway, $$\log\left(\frac23\right)=\log\left(1-\frac13\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n3^n}$$ and $$\log\left(\frac32\right)=\log\left(1+\frac12\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n2^n}$$ hence indeed you (re)proved that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n3^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n2^n}$$

Comment: @Did ...I'm really stupid. Thank you sir.

Comment: @R.Rengold Please refer to first sentence of previous comment...